# All but first query parameter stripped when using FB share dialogue on android chrome

Tags: android, facebook, google-chrome

I am using this:

```
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    display: 'popup',
    href: "http://blah.com/resource/123?utm_campaign=web&utm_content=side&utm_source=facebook"
  }, callback);
```

This shares properly using chrome and safari on desktop. On android chrome, clicking on the share button allows you to share via chrome (through FB mobile web app) or "Open with Facebook". Sharing via chrome here is no problem, but the other option of sharing within the Facebook app causes the URL to only contain the first query parameter, so instead of

> http://blah.com/resource/123?utm_campaign=web&utm_content=side&utm_source=facebook

It ends up being

> http://blah.com/resource/123?utm_campaign=web

I have also tried setting href to

```
"http://blah.com" + encodeURIComponent("/resource/123?utm_campaign=web&utm_content=side&utm_source=facebook")
```

and this caused the opposite to happen - chrome/safari share didn't work (it ended up sharing the encoded query string which isn't understood by the server/GA) but sharing via Facebook app when given the option in android chrome worked - the ultimate URL that was shared was the decoded query string.

Has anyone figured out or have an idea on how to preserve the query string for chrome web share and Facebook app share initiated through chrome?

Comment: +1 - Still struggling. Thanks for the direction that it only happens under chrome - i was in the progress of finding where and when it happens.